# Is there anyone who can help me about CKAN authorization?

Tags: authorization, ckan

I am Java developer and my customer wants to make web application using CKAN.

But he wants too many functions more over CKAN offers or not corresponds with CKAN's architecture.

So I decided to write Java program which has functions that customer wants and calls CKAN's RESTful API using Apache HttpComponent

But I encountered authorization issue.

Because my To-Be system will works without login to CKAN, I have to know users API-KEY when I call some apis need authorization.
But I can't get API-KEY unless login CKAN site(right?) and I think that getting someone's API-KEY by another way is nonsense.
If you don't think so, could you tell me how to get users API-KEY?

I also considered another way making all objects need authorization public.
But some apis send authorization error when I don't put API-KEY in Http header whether the object I intend to handle is public or private

Because of these reasons, development is been delaying.

Could you give me some advice?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get a user's API key is for the user herself to login to the CKAN web interface and go to their profile page.

If you're writing an API client, the way a client would normally work is to ask the user to enter their username and API key, either in a configuration file or into a GUI.